# Coinbase api - Sandbox possibility

Tags: coinbase-api

Maybe someone have seen the possibility to obtain sandbox access in the coinbase api for testing purpose like for coinbase-pro api ?

Comment: hey, it would be great to add a better explanation for the OP to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Following to an [article on Coinjournal](https://coinjournal.net/news/coinbase-announces-bitcoin-sandbox-environment-developers-merchants/), the URL https://sandbox.coinbase.com/ is related to sandbox but this URL is **no more available** today.

But you can use the URLs to request a sandbox API for Coinbase pro, you can find the list here : https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#sandbox

Before make your first call you need to create a API on your sandbox profile : https://public.sandbox.pro.coinbase.com/profile/api